# MYSQL SUM Syntax

Tags: mysql, database, syntax, phpmyadmin, sum

If I want to know the movie name and its sales total, can I use the query below?

```
Movie.Name, Movie.Sales, 
FROM Movie 
GROUP BY Movie.Name 
HAVING SUM (Movie.Sales)>120000 
ORDER BY SUM(Movie.Sales)DESC;
```

I know it’s best to write

```
Movie.Name, Movie.Sales, 
FROM Movie 
GROUP BY Movie.Name 
HAVING Movie.Sales>120000 
ORDER BY Movie.Sales DESC;
```

I was just wondering if the first one would still be considered a good answer in a test. BTW both queries give the same thing but SUM is not needed since Movie.Sales already has the total. Do you think it’s a bad answer?

Comment: "since Movie.Sales already has the total". No it doesn't, it just has the sales from a single row, not the sum of all the rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the first query will not work because it has an error. You are doing a `GROUP BY` on the `Movie.Name` field, but attempting to include a non-grouped field in your query without an aggregate function. Anywhere you want to use the `Movie.Sales` field, you'll have to use it in conjunction with the `SUM()` function.

```
SELECT Movie.Name, SUM(Movie.Sales) Sales
FROM Movie
GROUP BY Movie.Name
HAVING SUM(Movie.Sales)>120000
ORDER BY SUM(Movie.Sales) DESC
```

The above is the corrected version of your first query, but your second query is definitely correct, and probably best practice since the table is already aggregated.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. The first query worked though when I tried in in phpmyadmin and the right results were displayed. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: In MySQL, it doesn't actually return an error, but it will give you unpredictable results. In your query it probably only returned what *looked like* correct results because your table is already aggregated, so no aggregations were actually made. However, other database systems will actually return an error for this query.

Answer (score 0):

You must keep in mind that tha order by is always applicable to visible column 
in your case the first  select

```
select  Movie.Name, Movie.Sales, 
FROM Movie
GROUP BY Movie.Name HAVING SUM (Movie.Sales)>12000 0 
ORDER BY SUM(Movie.Sales)DESC;
```

containt two error  ... 
wrong `,` before FROM clause and the order by on a column not displayed

the second is the correct

Comment: Thank you sir! much appreciated